# Does xmp protocol for IR require special hardware support?

Tags: lirc

I am using an IR hat with Raspberry Pi. This hat supports both - transmitting IR as well as receiving IR.

I am using LIRC package on Pi. For my TV, I can make all the following tools work:

```
irrecord
irw
ir-keytable
irsend
```

However, nothing seems to work for Comcast Xfinity receiver/remote. Specifically, I am focused on making irw or ir-keytable work.

I believe Xfinity uses a protocol called xmp. When I run ir-keytable, I see that xmp protocol is present in the list of loaded protocols.

I am wondering if xmp protocol requires special support in the hardware that my IR hat does not have. Regards.